# Is this subobject-linkage warning a GCC bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I am getting a subobject-linkage warning with GCC that I do not understand. The warning can be demonstrated with the following code.

example.h:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

static constexpr int value{1};

template <auto& N> struct Base {};
struct Foo : Base<value> {};

#endif
```

example.cpp:

```
#include "example.h"
```

Compiling this yields the following output from GCC:

```
/app/example.h:7:8: error: 'Foo' has a base 'Base<value>' which has internal linkage [-Werror=subobject-linkage]
    7 | struct Foo : Base<value> {};
      |        ^~~
```

Godbolt link:
https://godbolt.org/z/M5eqz9qK6

If I put the contents of example.h directly into example.cpp then it compiles fine. Clang and msvc do not generate this same warning. Is there an issue with this code, or is this is a bug in GCC?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why `value` needs to have internal linkage (`static`)? Could you just give it external linkage, e.g. as `constexpr inline int value{1};`?

Comment: Note that since `value` has internal linkage, its value could be completely different in different translation units. There's no guarantee that `Base<value>` will be consistent between TUs, so `class Foo : Base<value>` is at high risk of an ODR violation. The warning is very sensible.

Comment: Nope, there is no reason. Using external linkage actually solves the issue, and thinking about it from this internal/external linkage perspective makes the warning make sense. Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a warning, not an error. It is well-formed C++ and would compile if you didn't use `-Werror`.

However, the warning is reasonable.

You are putting `Foo`'s definition in a header file, which usually means that it is intended to be included in multiple translation units.

`value` has internal storage duration, because it is a non-template, non-inline, non-`extern` const-qualified variable. (The `static` is redundant.)

As a consequence, in each translation unit `value` is a different object. And because `Base` takes a reference as template argument, then `Base<value>` are different specializations of `Base` in different translation units, because the template parameter references different objects in each.

Then, if you include the header in two different translation units, the program will have undefined behavior, because the definitions of `Foo` violate the one-definition rule as they are, roughly said, not semantically identical. The compiler has no way to decide whether `Foo` is supposed to have `Base<value1>` or `Base<value2>` as base class (where `value1` and `value2` are invented names for the two instances of `value` in the different translation units).

More precisely the one-definition rule not only requires that two definitions of the same class are formed by the exact same token sequence, but also that all names looked up in the definition refer to the same entity in each definition (with some exceptions that don't apply here). In fact, that `value` is used as by-reference template argument isn't even relevant. The difference in lookup, coupled with `value` being odr-used is sufficient to violate ODR. (See [[basic.def.odr]/13.9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.def.odr#13.9) for the precise rule.)

So, the warning is telling you that your header can never be included in more than one translation unit without causing undefined behavior, which likely is not intended.